# Reset Password Issue with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords, forgot-password

I'm using Devise in my Rails app and am running into an issue resetting passwords.

When I attempt to reset my password, I'm sent an email with a link to reset the password.  After filling out the form with the new password, I get the error "The webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome, and I get the following error in my logs:

```
Started GET "/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 14:22:05 -0500
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=JatMT1fE-fQwsCWsEdy6
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1.8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

I can't seem to find any information on how to fix this problem.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable
 ...
end
```

**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  ...
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Build::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => :registrations}

  devise_scope :user do
      post 'registrations' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'register'
      post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'login'
      delete 'sessions' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
    end

 resources :users do
     match 'users/:id' => 'users#username'
     get 'validate_username', on: :collection
     get 'validate_email', on: :collection
     get 'edit_profile', on: :member
     get :projects, on: :member
     get :favorites, on: :member
     get :collections, on: :member
     member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
      get :following
      get :followers
     end
  end
end
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

    respond_to :json

    def create
        user = User.new(params[:user])
        Rails.logger.info(user.inspect)
        # comment out following line to re-enable confirmation
        # resource.skip_confirmation!

        if user.save
          sign_in user
          render :status => 200,
               :json => { :success => true,
                          :info => "Registered",
                          :data => { :user => user,
                                     :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
        else
            redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: user.errors.full_messages[0]
            Rails.logger.info(user.errors.inspect)
          # render :status => :unprocessable_entity,
          #        :json => { :success => false,
          #                   :info => resource.errors,
          #                   :data => {} }
        end
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
            @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
        else
            # remove the virtual current_password attribute 
            params[:user].delete(:current_password)
            @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
        end

        if successfully_updated
            if params[:update_email]
                set_flash_message :alert, :signed_up_but_unconfirmed
                redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
            else            
                set_flash_message :notice, :updated
                sign_in @user, :bypass => true
                redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
            end
        else
            redirect_to :back, alert: resource.errors.full_messages[0]
        end
    end

        private

    # check if we need password to update user data
    def needs_password?(user,params)
        !params[:profile]
    end

    protected

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
        user_path(resource)
    end

end
```

Comment: how does the controller look?

Comment: I added the registration controller.

Answer (score 3):

Check your after_sign_in_path_for in ApplicationController and add redirect to root_url (not :back or request.env['HTTP_REFERER']) if it is password edit request.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, except that I noticed that there was a repeated redirect to the password reset URL.

I think @Sergey Sokolov has the right answer, although I modified my after_sign_in_path:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   if request.referer.include? "reset_password"
     root_path
   else
     request.referer
   end
end
```

so that in cases other than the password reset the user will return to the page that he or she signed in from.  This avoids an issue of a user following a password reset link in an email.

I was also doing something very stupid while troubleshooting and remained logged in as a different user when I was resetting the password for a different user while testing.  This causes very strange behavior.